# Writing out every title from a search result from an API

Tags: php, api, foreach

I'm working with a recipe API and I manage to write every recipe with the written search word, and I cant write out the title using `$contentSearch->recipes->title`, but I need an `foreach` loop, I guess, to get every title out. But I don't get it to work.

**So, how can I write out every title from the search result?**

My code below don't contain my try at the problem because I guess I'm too far out.

```
   $apiUrl = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=" . $apiKey . "&q=". $search ;


    // get the content of the file
    $contentSearch = json_decode(file_get_contents($apiUrl));

    $allRecipes =  json_encode($contentSearch->recipes);

    return $allRecipes;
```

When the above code is written, the result I get is (the two first examples):

```
[{"publisher":"Closet Cooking",
"title":"Bacon Wrapped Jalapeno Popper Stuffed Chicken",
"recipe_id":"35120"},
{"publisher":"Closet",
"title":"Buffalo Chicken Chowder",
"recipe_id":"35169"},
```

Comment: why are you calling json_encode on `$contentSearch->recipes`? you should be able to get it with `foreach($contentSearch->recipes as $recipe){ echo $recipe->title }`. do you mean that you want to return a list of all the titles?

Comment: Yes of course, I don't need to use json_encode, it was from the last step, when trying something else. Taking it away solved the problem, thank you! Yes, I wanna return a list of titles, so that you later can click on a title and see the recipe.

Comment: no problem. returning a list of titles is something that I put in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the titles you can do this easily with array_map. Here's a full example (with some dummy text for the JSON)

```
<?php
//Just some dummy text
$jsonString = <<<JSON
[{"publisher":"Closet Cooking",
"title":"Bacon Wrapped Jalapeno Popper Stuffed Chicken",
"recipe_id":"35120"},
{"publisher":"Closet",
"title":"Buffalo Chicken Chowder",
"recipe_id":"35169"}]
JSON;

//decode the json (just like you're doing)
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonString);

//loop over the titles and write it out like you asked
foreach($jsonArr as $recipe) {
        echo $recipe->title;
}

// but I noticed you also have a return so maybe you just want to return the titles?
function getTitle($recipeObj) {
        return $recipeObj->title;
}

// return a list of titles by mapping the getTitle function across the array of objects
return array_map(getTitle, $jsonArr);
```

Note that you don't have to use `array_map` you could just as easily do something like this if it's more understandable for you:

```
$titles = array();
foreach($jsonArr as $recipe){
     $titles[] = $recipe->title;
}
return $titles;
```